# Where to configure print server in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, print-server

Currently, all printing is handled by a windows print server - SERVER_A

Our domain controller is SERVER_DC

I've managed to blow up SERVER_A so need to restore print services to SERVER_DC for the time being - where do i configure this?

Comment: You may try adding more details of the problem you are facing, and exactly what you mean by "restore print services" - have you added a new server, installed a printer, and add it to your AD printers? What have you tried to do so far? The more details the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printmig is your friend (Google for details).  Unfortunately if you haven't got a backup there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any backup of SERVER_A?

If you don't, then you need to reconfigure everything from scratch on SERVER_DC:

- Connect printers (directly or via TCP/IP printing)
- Install drivers
- Share printers
- Set permissions
- Etc.

You will also need to tell all your users they should now use **`\\SERVER_DC\SomePrinter`** instead of **`\\SERVER_A\SomePrinter`**; if you configure printers for users via logon scripts and/or GPOs, this will not be too difficult. If each user just manually looks up printers and connects to them, then there'll be a lot more work.

Comment: this is unfortunately what i've ended up doing...
Do you have any examples of login scripts i can use to set peoples printers as required?

Answer (score 0):

Check this how to: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775791%28WS.10%29.aspx

hth's

Comment: also create a DNS record (A or Cname) for "Server_A" and point it to "Server_DC", so your users do not need to know a new server name, during reconfig's (if any)

Comment: This usually doesn't work *too* well with Windows sharing...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recreate the printers on the DC then share and make sure they are published to AD so users can refind (using search) them without you having to go desk to desk